# Unslider on Image Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using unslider, jquery light slider in my website which is working but can I keep the plugin in my image hover ?

I have tried these but doesnot work:

```
$(function() {
    $('.banner').unslider({
        autoplay:false;
    });
});
$("#banner").hover(function(){
    if($('#banner').autoplay('false')){
        autoplay : true;
    }, function (){
        autoplay: false;
    }
});
```

Comment: autoplay is an object setting, not a function like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage is quite strange and I guess you may want to temporarily stop sliding when you hover the banner. After checking out the documentation of unslider, I guess you may have a test on the following snippet:

```
$(function() {
    var slidey = $('.banner').unslider({}),
        data = slidey.data('unslider');

    // I don't really know the relationship of $('.banner') and $('#banner') in your HTML code. 

    $('.banner').hover(
        function() {
            data.stop();
        },
        function() {
            data.start();
        }
    );
});
```